# Site Name Change & Scope Redefinition

Tags: discussion, status-completed

This is an update post about the goings on of the site:

- [Goings on 1](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/906/refocusing-from-health-to-medical-sciences)
- [Goings on 2](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/768/defibrillating-health-se/775#775)
- [Goings on 3](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/945/please-communicate-what-are-the-next-steps-for-this-site/946#946)

It's been a few months since all of this has been brought up and I wanted to share that it's now all back on the radar.  I have had an initial discussion with some of the members of this site in the [Waiting Room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22477/the-waiting-room) chat.  Feel free to jump in there to get caught up.

Basically, this post is to update you that:

1. We're likely going to change the name of the site.
2. We're likely going to change the scope of the site.
3. We need feedback and suggestions to make this work.

Let's revisit this thread on Sept. 12 and see where we are.  Next steps will follow.

Thank you all for your patience and your willingness to stick through this! Let's continue to help make this site as helpful and robust as it can be!

Comment: Looking forward to it! Thanks for communicating so openly, and most important for *listening* to us.

Comment: Sept. 12 is today, only one day after you posted this. On a small site like this, think it's better to give the users at least one full week to notice the announcement, no? (i.e. better revisit the thread and start actions on 17-18 this month.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard This change was announced way before in the chat, the changes are crystal clear and have been agreed upon before. AFAIK Juan wanted to chat with the mods and let us know of the progress today. I recommended to create a new post with a schedule of what will happen when instead of featuring the 4 month old post by JonEricson, so this basically was prompted by me. I don't think we need any more time for revisiting, and at least 7 users have seen the meta post (and I can't think of many more active users). re:Juan I absolutely love that you are considered a "new contributor".

Comment: I second what Narusan says; this conversation has been going on for a long time and there has been plenty of opportunity to offer alternative input. We went through the relevant meta topics with Juan and it was clear that there wasn't any real dissent registered, just a matter of specifics at this point and getting buy-in from the current mod team.

Comment: @all But I am somehow concerned about the lack of participation from the mod team in most of this for some time now. It's already -1 member. Do they disagree, do they not care, are they busy, have they overlooked this? 1001 possibilities. For a lot of these I'd not like to steamroller them.

Comment: I'm still waiting for a response.  Nothing yet.

Comment: One of them hasn't been around in months I believe; the other is in and out and was active today, so I'm not sure.

Comment: @BryanKrause Susan resigned recently, but michaelpri has been last active on SE as such 2 days ago, JohnP reviewed some flags 6 hours ago.

Comment: JohnP I knew was active; michaelpri may be active on SE but last activity on health was in July I think.

Comment: The name has not yet propagated to the [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com).

Comment: some tags might have to go, such as https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/home-remedies

Answer (score 11):

I have pinged the mod team twice and have not heard from them yet.  I will wait until the end of day and update here. I'm thinking that the next step will be to change the site name.  If there are no other views, let's go with:

**Medical Sciences**

---

**EDIT**

This is now live!

Comment: Where did you ping? I have received no notices, and I am on SE daily, multiple times.

Comment: @JohnP I pinged you in the Mod Chatroom

Comment: Never got it, but I checked earlier and responded. :)

Comment: Not a problem, just glad we were able to connect. :)

Comment: The site name changed right in front of me about 10 minutes ago.  It is now quarter past midnight UK time

Answer (score 9):

Presuming "Medical Sciences" will be the new name, I propose "Med" as a shorthand for the icon to replace the "H" rather than "MS."

Comment: Agree. MS will be mistaken as multiple sclerosis, Microsoft, and a host of other things.

Comment: Med sounds good.  Nice!

Comment: Good choice and it looks great!

Comment: I'm seeing a blue "med" rather than a black one here on meta.  Is anybody else seeing that?  (I mean in the browser favicon and site switcher; the actual site design is as expected.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio Are you on mobile? My icons on mobile have been all messed up, but it isn't specific to medical sciences.

Comment: No, desktop.  A bunch of my icons were messed up on Friday, but they've all been fixed now -- except this one.  Everything else is normal, but meta Medical Sciences is blue. https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIMTe.png

Comment: @MonicaCellio My iPhone browser (with desktop version of the site) is experiencing the same problem

Answer (score 7):

I just visited the site for the first time in several weeks and *wow*, the front page looks *much* better now.  Good job everybody!

(I know; this isn't really an answer to this question.  But this seemed like the least-incorrect place to put this.)

Comment: Although almost "according to plan", I myself am a bit at unease about the still too high hold&close ratio as well as kind and the level of activity in general. So, thanks for this perspective. And if you feel like it, pour on some more balsam. Whether personal observations or SE specific technicalities. Some motivational head patting would not be against the doctor's recommendations for therapy ;)

Comment: @LangLangC I think the high close ratio is due in part to the fact that we haven't completed editing the help section. It doesn't yet make it clear that medical advice questions are off topic, and those are the vast majority of the questions being closed. I will try to get on that task soon.

Comment: I think even when the help is edited we will still have a lot of hold/close for those purposes, and I think that's okay as long as there are other questions that are good. I think a more important challenge is to get people with good questions involved rather than worry too much about the people with bad ones.

Comment: I agree, and it's also important to downvote bad questions and upvote goods ones so the bad questions get pushed down the queue and out of sight. I've begun downvoting every question I close in order to speed this process along.

Comment: @CareyGregory unless it's a (good) dupe, I assume?  That's the one case where closed questions still provide value, as pointers to the place with the answers.

Comment: @MonicaCellio  Yes, agreed. I don't downvote (good) dupes because I don't consider them bad questions; they're just misplaced questions. Same with questions that can be migrated to other exchanges.

Answer (score 6):

Other changes that will eventually need to be made along with the name change (please add and update):

- [Fixing How-to-Ask](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) again
- <del>[Change the word Health to Medical Sciences on Area 51, and update the description](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66048?phase=beta) to match new site definition (http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=newest&page=2)</del> is fixed
- <del>[Change the name](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/965/11231) of the main chatroom. ["The Waiting Room"](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/22477/the-waiting-room) is begging for people in line to get their personal medical advice answered…</del> is fixed
- update the scope and fix https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic
- update the tour: with everything running smoothly and another mod on our hands, it might be a good idea to revisit the tour. AFAIK the current unicorn question is a placeholder because our other posts don’t qualify. Maybe the qualifications can be revisited by the SE staff if there are the resources present? I.e. not being able to include hyperlinks makes it difficult for any well-researched answer from us being up there, since they all include hyperlink references.

Comment: This all sounds good to me.  Let me know when this is all decided on and I can make the request for the changes.

Comment: @JuanM Is the definition updated as well? (*MedicalSciences is a site primarily directed at professionals in medical and allied health fields, students of those professions, related academics, and others with a sound understanding of medicine and healthcare-related sciences.*) It isn’t on Area51, but Area51 still knows us as „Health“. I don‘t know where else to find that information...

Comment: @Narusan That's working its way into the queue. We'll get it changed!

Comment: @Narusan The Area 51 title and definition has been updated.

Comment: @Narusan The site audience description has now been updated as well.

Comment: [The chatroom name has been changed](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22477/grand-rounds)!

Comment: @JuanM I noticed that at the bottom of every question there‘s now a How-To-Ask Box. Can that be modified on a site to site basis? Because maybe we could put a large big sign there saying don’t ask about your personal health. It is not identical to the How-To-Ask-Page, although it is titled the same

Answer (score 3):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Days after the other icon disruptions (wrong icons for sites in HNQ and other places) were resolved, I'm still seeing a blue icon for this meta site:

[image: screenshot]

It also appears in the inbox (I just got a comment ping here).  This is with the full site in both Firefox and Chrome; another user [reports](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/956/site-name-change-scope-redefinition/961?noredirect=1#comment5113_961) it happens on an iPhone too.  It seems to be the same behavior we were seeing Friday, but it's just this one meta site.

Comment: OK, I'll need to report that and get it added to the queue.

Comment: This has been added to the queue. :)

Comment: My bad - this wasn't even caching, this was me copy/pasting the wrong icons into the images folder for the meta site. :)

Comment: @AdamLear oopsie!  Looks good now.